# Facebook android v2 deprecated

Tags: android, facebook, deprecated

I got a notification saying that in June Facebook for Android v2 will be deprecated and no longer work.  I replaced my facebook jar with the latest v3 jar and the existing code in my android app still all works.  They are all marked with @deprecated.  Is that enough to meet the requirements or do I have to recode my entire facebook integration before June?

thx!

Answer (score 0):

You are better of rewriting the program (using the new api) because if it is marked as deprecated it will likely be removed from the code at some time rendering your program useless.

Comment: If you are satisfied with my answer please accept it or tell me what else it needs.